# How to limit access to .zip files to all but a specific folder with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a download site where I blocked access to .zip files in order to force users to go through my download process (simply means u have to register before you download).

Now I am also making a java arcade and I want the applet to be able to download zip files from a specific directory on it and play them.

Right now I am using something like in my site's root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule .*\.(zip)$ http://www.google.com [R,NC]
```

The question is how do I tell it not to include the folder "arcade" in it.
What do I modify in the above code or what do I put in the arcade/.htaccess file to make it possible to link to zips..

Thanks!
 - Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the RewriteCond directive. You need something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/arcade/
RewriteRule \.zip$ - [F]
```

I have also changed the way you block access to .zip files. It's better to return a 403 error code.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#exclude the arcade folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/arcade [NC] 
RewriteRule .*\.(zip)$ http://www.google.com [R,NC]
```

Instead of the redirect you could also give a 404 as below. Also simplified the match for the RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/arcade [NC] 
RewriteRule  \.zip$ - [R=404,NC]
```